# Does convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution even if random variable takes value in metric space

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence

Consider a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of random variables taking values in a metric space $S$. If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability does that imply $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution ?

Answer (score 4):

Let us first talk about how we should define convergence in probability for random variables with values in a metric space $S$. We want to say that

$$X_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\to X :\iff \forall \epsilon > 0: \mathbb{P}(d(X_n,X) \geq \epsilon) \stackrel{n \to \infty}\to 0$$

But there is a problem here. How are we sure that, given two random variables $X,Y$, the map $\omega \mapsto  d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))$ is measurable? This is needed such that the above probability is well-defined (the event $\{d(X_n,X) \geq \epsilon\}$ should be in our $\sigma$-algebra for all $\epsilon > 0$).

In general, we can't ensure this. But if $S$ is **separable** (which declares the letter $S$), then one can prove that the above map is measurable so we don't have problems.

Under this assumption, you can check that it still holds that $$X_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}} \to X \implies X_n \stackrel{d} \to X$$

using the same proof as before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain how separability helps to make the map measurable ?

Comment: This is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436661/measurability-of-distance-function. The point is that we can view $d(X,Y)$ as the composition $d \circ (X,Y)$ and the natural $\sigma$-algebra's on this coincide if $S$ is separable, giving the measurability of the composition. Proposition 8.1.7 in Cohn's book "Measure theory" on p243 proves that $\mathcal{B}(X \times Y) = \mathcal{B}(X) \times \mathcal{B}(Y)$ when $X,Y$ are separable topological spaces, which is exactly what is needed here.